# Should Java Heap Monitor show multiple instances for single object

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, libgdx, asset-management

I'm trying to find a memory leak in my Android Game (LibGDX).

I Dumped the Java Heap and looked at my Asset Manager. It is showing 9 instances.

In my code there is a single Object for Asset Manager which is being passed through multiple layers.

i.e -

Game Class creates Asset Manager object

Game Class passes said object through to Screen Class constructor.

Screen Class assigns object to its own private variable for easier referencing.

Screen Class passes said object through to Sprite Class constructor.

And so on...

But in my code there is really only one instance being passed through multiple layers. Should the heap say 9? Is this possibly causing a memory leak.

I'm assuming there's a memory leak because this starts to happen on my Desktop and I need to kill the app:

[image]

Comment: The thing is, objects in Java are created by calling `new` only. Either that "9" means nine _references_ to the same object, or something has created nine Asset Manager's using the `new` keyword. You could put some log statements in the constructor to count creations.

Comment: It must mean 9 references to the same object then, since I only call `new` once. I take it that's not causing the memory leak then